# Django + tox: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest, tox

I'm migrating a Django project to use Tox and pytest.  I'm getting the following when running tox.

```
_________________________________________ ERROR collecting fixtureless/tests/test_django_project/test_app/tests/test_factory.py _________________________________________
fixtureless/tests/test_django_project/test_app/tests/test_factory.py:10: in <module>
    from test_app.models import ModelOne, ModelTwo
fixtureless/tests/test_django_project/test_app/models.py:11: in <module>
    class ModelOne(models.Model):
.tox/py36-django21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:87: in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
.tox/py36-django21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:249: in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
.tox/py36-django21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:132: in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
E   django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Here is my tox file.

```
[tox]
skipsdist = true
envlist =
    py{36,37}-django21,
    py{36,37}-django22,

# Add environment to use the default python3 installation
[testenv]
setenv =
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}:{toxinidir}/fixtureless/tests/test_django_project
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = settings.postgres
deps =
    pillow
    psycopg2
    pytest
    django21: Django>=2.1,<2.2
    django22: Django>=2.2,<2.3
commands = pytest
```

It's like `django.setup()` isn't being invoked or something.  I'm fairly new to tox still.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is an open source project ([django-fixtureless](https://github.com/ricomoss/django_fixtureless)) and I have been successfully running the Django test suite using the instructions outlined [here](https://github.com/ricomoss/django_fixtureless/blob/master/docs/testing.md).

Comment: But where's the `pytest-django` plugin in the list of deps? `pytest` alone doesn't provide a django test runner, you need a plugin that ships that.

Comment: @hoefling That is exactly my problem here.  If you'd like to post an answer, I'd be happy to get you some reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't know how to run `pytest`-style test functions. Plain `pytest` also doesn't provide a django integration. You can either

- write a custom test runner (a minimal example):

  ```
  # myapp/runner.py

  class PytestRunner:
      def run_tests(self, test_labels):
          import pytest    
          return pytest.main(test_labels)
  ```

  and configure your app to use it instead of the default `DiscoverRunner`:

  ```
  # myapp/settings.py
  TEST_RUNNER = 'myapp.runner.PytestRunner'
  ```

  Now `python manage.py test` will invoke `pytest` instead of the default `unittest`.
- Or use the [`pytest-django`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-django/) plugin. Add it to `deps`:

  ```
  deps =
      ...
      pytest
      pytest-django
      ...
  ```

  This doesn't provide integration with `manage.py test` per se, but you will be able to invoke tests as usual via `pytest`:

  ```
  $ pytest --ds=myapp.settings
  ...
  ```

  The plugin also provides many useful fixtures that reimplement Django's test helpers (like `RequestFactory`, `Client` etc) so you can do a complete port of the `unittest`-style test classes to `pytest`-style test functions. Refer to `pytest-django` [docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for configurations details and code examples.